# vfork doesn't work as expected on OSX, how to explain?

Tags: macos, unix, system-calls, vfork

```
#include "apue.h"

int globvar = 6;

int main(void) {
    int var;
    pid_t pid;

    var = 99;
    printf("before vfork\n");
    if ((pid = vfork()) < 0) {
        err_sys("vfork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        globvar++;
        var++;
        printf("in child process:\n");
        printf("pid = %ld, glob = %d, var = %d\n", (long)getpid(), globvar, var);

        _exit(0);
    }
    printf("in parent process:\n");
    printf("pid = %ld, glob = %d, var = %d\n", (long)getpid(), globvar, var);
    exit(0);
}
```

I tested this code on macOS(Monterey 12.6), the output is:

```
before vfork
in parent process:
pid = 10540, glob = 6, var = 99
in child process:
pid = 10541, glob = 7, var = 100
```

`vfork` should ensure that child process execute first. Why `parent` log first?  Could anyone explain it for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this unexpected? Once the process has forked, the two processes execute independently, so the sequence things happen in depends on the quirks of the system's process scheduler. This is a classic [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), which means that you can't count on things happening in any specific order.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Historically, the BSD `vfork()` suspended the parent process until the child exited or called `execve()` (And the child shared memory with the parent until then). I don't think POSIX required that behavior in the days before it removed `vfork()` from the standard, and have no idea if OS X ever behaved that way. Personally, it falls into the category of functions to just never use because of that oddness.